# Opened VS 2013 Solution in VS 2017. Now Razor intellisense doesn't work

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

So, I have an MVC 3 web project/solution for VS 2013.  I decided to open it in VS 2017, get all modern.  Visual Studio did it's thing.  Note I did NOT upgrade the MVC versions, I was content to stay at 3 and Razor at version 1.0.

Now, when I open up my cshtml pages, all the Razor syntax has squiggly red lines.  If I F12 on the @Html in my cshtml page, it takes me to  System.Web.WebPages.WebPage instead of  System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage as it is supposed to.

I've researched this a lot.  And I've tried pretty well everything out there.  I've deleted the obj and bin folder contents, wiped out the ComponentModelCache, and the .vs folder, and the .suo file.  I don't have Resharper on 2017.  I've checked the .config files, and all seems in order; all appear to have the correct references.

I'm really at my wits end here.  This is incredibly annoying.  I'm hoping someone out there has a better answer than what I've found to date.

Any help appreciated.  I really don't want to have to roll it back to VS 2013, but I might just have to.

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the solution?

Comment: You need to upgrade the Razor / MVC versions to versions that VS2017 supports.

Comment: @dustinos3 - of course.  I am a bit foolish, but I'm not that dumb...(I hope).

Comment: @Slaks - But it still builds and runs.  I can debug and it works.  I was thinking about upgrading the MVC/Razor, but was worried about potential backwards compatibility issues.

Comment: But the VS _editor_ tooling only supports newer versions.

Comment: @Slaks - well then...I'd like to withdraw a previous comment.  Apparently I am stupid.  I will give that whirl.  Hopefully that does it.

Comment: @Slaks.  I want to Accept your answer but I don't seem to have the option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade the Razor / MVC versions to versions that VS2017 supports.